# Getting error when try to consume soap service from nop commerce

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, soap, nopcommerce

I'm developing a plugin were i have done something like this code

```
[ChildActionOnly]
[HttpPost,ActionName("Configure")]
[FormValueRequired("test")]
public ActionResult TestSms(SmsRobiModel model)
{
    bd.com.robi.bmpws.CMPWebService objCmpService = new bd.com.robi.bmpws.CMPWebService();
    bd.com.robi.bmpws.ServiceClass sc = objCmpService.SendTextMessage("username", "password", "sendernumber", "receivernumber", "test msg");
}
```

but I get an error on this line and here is the error:

> bd.com.robi.bmpws.ServiceClass sc = objCmpService.SendTextMessage("username", "password", "sendernumber", "receivernumber", "test msg");

Getting an error when try to consume soap service from nopCommerce.

I am trying to develop a SMS plugin in nopCommerce. I did everything for 
a plugin but the sms send method is not functioning.

A SMS provider give me a soap service URL. I added it into my class library project, build it and install it in nopCommerce.

I am getting this error:

> System.Net.WebException: The request failed with an empty response. at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall) at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters) at Nop.Plugin.SMS.Robi.bd.com.robi.bmpws.CMPWebService.SendTextMessage(String Username, String Password, String From, String To, String Message) at Nop.Plugin.SMS.Robi.SmsRobiProvider.SendSms(String text, Int32 orderId, SmsRobiSettings settings) at Nop.Plugin.SMS.Robi.OrderPlacedEventConsumer.HandleEvent(OrderPlacedEvent eventMessage) at Nop.Services.Events.EventPublisher.PublishToConsumer[T](IConsumer`1 x, T eventMessage) in d:\MahadyLiveProjects\eshoptest\Libraries\Nop.Services\Events\EventPublisher.cs:line 40

Comment: Seems not cleared, *sms provider* which one? how you developed a plugin, and how you configured it.

Comment: This type of exception get when you try to call an `HTTPS` service as `HTTP`

Comment: Yes! First I also think like that. then I change HTTP to https in app.confige file     

<applicationSettings>
        <Nop.Plugin.SMS.Robi.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="Nop_Plugin_SMS_Robi_bd_com_robi_bmpws_CMPWebService"
                serializeAs="String">
                <value>https://webservice</value>
            </setting>
        </Nop.Plugin.SMS.Robi.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>

Comment: How many URLs given by provider?

Comment: *I added it into my class library project* **What do you mean?** Is there any configuration page to add URL?

Comment: one WSDL SOAP link

Comment: In nop commerce when we want to develop a plugin we need to create a class library project.

Comment: bd.com.robi.bmpws.CMPWebService objCmpService = new bd.com.robi.bmpws.CMPWebService();
bd.com.robi.bmpws.ServiceClass sc = objCmpService.SendTextMessage("username", "password", "sendernumber", "receivernumber", "test msg");

Comment: Please, edit your question and put your cod there only!

Comment: Do you meant , remove error message and replace my code ?

Comment: No, both should add in the question, like *I'm developing a plugin were i have done something like this code but i get an error on this line and here is the error*

Comment: `[ChildActionOnly]
[HttpPost,ActionName("Configure")]
[FormValueRequired("test")]
public ActionResult TestSms(SmsRobiModel model)
{
 bd.com.robi.bmpws.CMPWebService objCmpService = new bd.com.robi.bmpws.CMPWebService();
 bd.com.robi.bmpws.ServiceClass sc = objCmpService.SendTextMessage("username", "password", "sendernumber", "receivernumber", "test msg");
}`

Comment: I can give my source code to you. If you want to examine it. @Div